changing an object key's values
How can I change the **obj2 **values instead of doing it one by one as shown  is there a way that doing it at once ?
const obj1={
  name:`serag`,
  age:30,
  children:
  {
    daughter:`leila`,
    son:`seif`
  }
};

const obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));

let {name,age,children}=obj2;
// obj2.name =`omar`;
// obj2.age=30;
// obj2.children.daughter=`huda`;
// obj2.children.son=`ahmed`;

I just started to learn JS consider myself a beginner

What you're asking (technically) is: how to clone an object in JavaScript. There's many methods as already answered herein. But, thought this might help if you wanted to research it some more.

If this data structure is supposed to represent real "people", you're likely not going to have fun with it in its current form for long ... As soon as you will encounter a person that has more than one son or more than one daughter, how are you going to stick that info into there then ...?

Really appreciates your replies, I did searched yesterday for how to shallow or deep copy before asking and all works fine the thing is how if I have a lot information in the copied object and I want to edit it without going on one by one it would be tedious to do so that's what I meant , I believe there is another way than using object but I wanted to know if it's done while using this DS first as I learn down the road @C3roe

One of the many ways is to use spread operator.
const obj3 = {...obj1}

You can also use Object.assing() for shallow copy.
const shallowCopy = Object.assign({}, obj1);

For more information please have a look at this.
Hope, this helps.

Thank you I did a deep copy of the original object but I meant if there is a way to edit /assign new values to new object instead of doing assigning every key after another => the commented lines.

maybe using a for loop. something like
for (const key in obj1) obj2[key] = obj1[key]
that's the gist of it, not sure it is what you're looking for

@Commodore64 thanks , that helped me while thinking to use obj.assign method didn't beforehand that I can loop the object until you tell me tho xd

You can use object assign to clone and modify the object at once.
// obj1 
const obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1, {
  name: "omar",
  age: 35,
  children: Object.assign({}, obj1.children, {
    daughter: "huda",
    son: "ahmed",
  }),
});


thank you @araldhafeeri this adds to my knowledge <3
